# How can I access any directive from directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I have two directive in one module. I want to access from A directive to B directive. Because A directive should be used B'scope.
 A directive:

```
angular.module('main').directive('ADirective',  function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl:'kk.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {

            $scope.usedParameter="test",
```

scope:true});

B directive:

```
angular.module('main').directive('BDirective',  function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl:'kk.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {

            //$scope.ascopeValue =
```

scope:true});

In html I m using like that:(b directive template)

```
<div tab-view name="Main">
        <div tab name="A">

            <div class="panel-default">
                <a-directive></a-directive>

            </div>
        </div>
```

If I inject the b directive like that :

```
angular.module('main').directive('aDirective', [ 'bDirective', function (bDirective) {
```

Unknown provider:  error is coming.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here? what does "A directive should be used in B's scope"? that doesn't really make sense, in terms of the way that angular scopes apply to directives.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject a directive. But what would you like to do with the directive? If they share the same logic you should create a service or a factory. If you want to use the directive in the HTML you don't have to inject it, you can just use it like you did, but WITHOUT injecting anything.

**Edit:**

In this case you can pass a variable with an attribute:

```
angular.module('main').directive('BDirective',  function () {

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl:'kk.html',
    scope: {
         passedAttribute= '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
         console.log($scope.passedAttribute);
```

And your HTML of the a-directive:

```
<div tab-view name="Main">
    <div tab name="A">

        <div class="panel-default">
            <b-directive passed-attribute="variableFromThisScope"></b-directive>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want to use its scope. But its not parent scope. SO I can not use. Sop I want to use 'ascopeValue' variable from A directive

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in sharing information between a directive and the element the directive is inside, you would need to expose the variable as a parameter on the directive, and define it in `scope`.

For example:

```
angular.module('main').directive('ADirective',  function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl:'kk.html',
        scope: {
            usedParameter : '=ascopeValue'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.usedParameter="test",   
    });


<div tab-view name="Main">
    <div tab name="A">
        <div class="panel-default">
            <a-directive ascopeValue="bscopeVariable"></a-directive>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When defining your scope variables, you have 3 options:

- `@` to bind the *value* passed in (interpolated)
- `=` to bind the *property* passed in (two way bound)
- `&` to bind a *function* passed in (directive calls function in outer scope)